# Vim at Ubuntu 11.04: Working with clipboard of Unity

Tags: vim, ubuntu, clipboard

The problem is, the old-way method to work with X11 clipboard (through "plus" register) doesn't work in Unity. Has anyone met the problem? And how it was solved?

Comment: Try Ctrl-Shift-V for paste, Ctrl-Shift-C for copy. It's a terminal hack I think, not a vim hack.

Comment: Yes, that I know. But the method isn't useful when creating a macro that puts data to the clipboard. And I need to handle exactly such a situation.

Comment: I've already tried before. "Star" register doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem solves itself after GVim installation. Then "plus" register works as it should be.

Comment: Same here, could use '+' register after installing vim-gnome

Answer (score 1):

Even if you do not have `gvim` installed or `xterm_clipboard` enabled, you may use `xsel` to manage your clipboard (install it via `apt-get`).

I hope my script will help you: https://github.com/FUT/config-files/blob/master/vim-dotfiles/vim/settings/clipboard.vim

Comment: You can also write buffer contents to the standard input of another program - `:w !program`. It's very useful especially with `xsel -b` - `:w !xsel -b` to copy contents to the clipboard which allows to paste the content somewhere else by pressing _Ctrl+V_.

Answer (score 1):

Use :
`sudo apt-get install vim-gtk`
This will install vim with clipboard support.
Run as before:
 `vim`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the unity desktop but I know that it is based on gnome libraries. So if you can use dbus to interact with unitys clipboard, you may consider writing a shell script which uses dbus to set the clipboard content. This script can in turn receive its input from vim if you assign a map to a filter command. Of course this works similarly if you know any other commandline utility which can set the clipboard content.
I used to have the following maps in .vimrc for the old dcop and klipper (the KDE clipboard) which you might customize:

`:vmap k  :w! $HOME/.vimclip<CR>:silent execute "!dcop klipper klipper setClipboardContents \"$(cat $HOME/.vimclip)\" &>/dev/null &"<CR>:redraw!<CR>

:nmap z  :silent execute "!dcop klipper klipper getClipboardContents > $HOME/.vimclip"<CR>:r $HOME/.vimclip<CR>:redraw!<CR>`

E.g. to copy press k after making a selection in visual mode. Note, that it copies and pasts line wise.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try today at home. Interesting thing, at work machine, where I've updated from the previous version, "plus" register still works. I thinks it's because old libraries were left to provide compatibility with old software already installed in the system.

Comment: I can't check the maps because I don't have a system with KDE. But I see the idea to use an external program as a proxy between Vim and Unity's clipboard. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the problem again after while. Must say I use vim in GNOME Terminal, not GVim that is also installed.

What is interesting the plus register stopped working approximately at the same time on different computers of mine.

First I though it was a bug because the graphical version was installed as before. But at the end I just started GVim and tested the plus register there. It was working. After that the register began working in the terminal too.

So if you meet the problem again, when you have already installed GVim, just start it. This should help.